# Coupling is too high - how to design this class better?

Tags: design-patterns, coupling

Running FxCop on my code, I get this warning:

> Microsoft.Maintainability :
>   'FooBar.ctor is coupled with 99
>   different types from 9 different
>   namespaces. Rewrite or refactor the
>   method to decrease its class coupling,
>   or consider moving the method to one
>   of the other types it is tightly
>   coupled with. A class coupling above
>   40 indicates poor maintainability, a
>   class coupling between 40 and 30
>   indicates moderate maintainability,
>   and a class coupling below 30
>   indicates good maintainability.

My class is a landing zone for all messages from the server. The server can send us messages of different EventArgs types:

```
public FooBar()
{
    var messageHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<EventArgs>>();
    messageHandlers.Add(typeof(YouHaveBeenLoggedOutEventArgs), HandleSignOut);
    messageHandlers.Add(typeof(TestConnectionEventArgs), HandleConnectionTest);
    // ... etc for 90 other types
}
```

The "HandleSignOut" and "HandleConnectionTest" methods have little code in them; they usually pass the work off to a function in another class.

How can I make this class better with lower coupling?

Comment: I like the responses here but maybe someplace like RefactorMyCode.com might be a better place for it.  It's a little easier for everyone to post code in their responses on that site.

Comment: Ok, I posted the example, check it out

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have the classes that do the work register for events they're interested in...an [event broker](http://msforge.net/blogs/paki/archive/2007/11/20/EventBroker-implementation-in-C_2300_-full-source-code.aspx) pattern.

```
class EventBroker {
   private Dictionary<Type, Action<EventArgs>> messageHandlers;

   void Register<T>(Action<EventArgs> subscriber) where T:EventArgs {
      // may have to combine delegates if more than 1 listener
      messageHandlers[typeof(T)] = subscriber; 
   }

   void Send<T>(T e) where T:EventArgs {
      var d = messageHandlers[typeof(T)];
      if (d != null) {
         d(e);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was just talking about.  I'm up voting yours because of the example.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for the answer, we'll take this into consideration. I think I'll accept yours as the answer until I see a better one.

Comment: Interesting! I ran into the same issue. Is it fast enough? I mean, can I use it in a game with an update loop?

Answer (score 5):

You could also use some sort of IoC framework, like Spring.NET, to inject the dictionary.  This way, if you get a new message type, you don't have to recompile this central hub - just change a config file.

---

The long awaited example:

Create a new console app, named Example, and add this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Spring.Context.Support;

namespace Example
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MessageBroker broker = (MessageBroker) ContextRegistry.GetContext()["messageBroker"];
            broker.Dispatch(null, new Type1EventArgs());
            broker.Dispatch(null, new Type2EventArgs());
            broker.Dispatch(null, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public class MessageBroker
    {
        private Dictionary<Type, object> handlers;

        public Dictionary<Type, object> Handlers
        {
            get { return handlers; }
            set { handlers = value; }
        }

        public void Dispatch<T>(object sender, T e) where T : EventArgs
        {
            object entry;
            if (Handlers.TryGetValue(e.GetType(), out entry))
            {
                MessageHandler<T> handler = entry as MessageHandler<T>;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler.HandleMessage(sender, e);
                }
                else
                {
                    //I'd log an error here
                    Console.WriteLine("The handler defined for event type '" + e.GetType().Name + "' doesn't implement the correct interface!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //I'd log a warning here
                Console.WriteLine("No handler defined for event type: " + e.GetType().Name);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface MessageHandler<T> where T : EventArgs
    {
        void HandleMessage(object sender, T message);
    }

    public class Type1MessageHandler : MessageHandler<Type1EventArgs>
    {
        public void HandleMessage(object sender, Type1EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type 1, " + args.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class Type2MessageHandler : MessageHandler<Type2EventArgs>
    {
        public void HandleMessage(object sender, Type2EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type 2, " + args.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class Type1EventArgs : EventArgs {}

    public class Type2EventArgs : EventArgs {}
}
```

And an app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core"/>
      <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="config://spring/objects"/>
    </context>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">

      <object id="messageBroker" type="Example.MessageBroker, Example">
        <property name="handlers">
          <dictionary key-type="System.Type" value-type="object">
            <entry key="Example.Type1EventArgs, Example" value-ref="type1Handler"/>
            <entry key="Example.Type2EventArgs, Example" value-ref="type2Handler"/>
          </dictionary>
        </property>
      </object>
      <object id="type1Handler" type="Example.Type1MessageHandler, Example"/>
      <object id="type2Handler" type="Example.Type2MessageHandler, Example"/>
    </objects>
  </spring>
</configuration>
```

Output:

```
Type 1, Example.Type1EventArgs
Type 2, Example.Type2EventArgs
No handler defined for event type: EventArgs
```

As you can see, `MessageBroker` doesn't know about any of the handlers, and the handlers don't know about `MessageBroker`.  All of the mapping is done in the app.config file, so that if you need to handle a new event type, you can add it in the config file.  This is especially nice if other teams are defining event types and handlers - they can just compile their stuff in a dll, you drop it into your deployment and simply add a mapping.

The Dictionary has values of type object instead of `MessageHandler<>` because the actual handlers can't be cast to `MessageHandler<EventArgs>`, so I had to hack around that a bit.  I think the solution is still clean, and it handles mapping errors well.  Note that you'll also need to reference Spring.Core.dll in this project.  You can find the libraries [here](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/springnet/Spring.NET-1.1.2.zip?modtime=1210044370&big_mirror=0), and the documentation [here](http://springframework.net/docs/1.1.2/reference/html/index.html).  The [dependency injection chapter](http://springframework.net/docs/1.1.2/reference/html/objects.html#objects-dependencies) is relevant to this.  Also note, there is no reason you need to use Spring.NET for this - the important idea here is dependency injection.  Somehow, something is going to need to tell the broker to send messages of type a to x, and using an IoC container for dependency injection is a good way to have the broker not know about x, and vice versa.

Some other SO question related to IoC and DI:

- [Difference between Dependency Injection (DI) & Inversion of Control (IOC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139299/difference-between-dependency-injection-di-inversion-of-control-ioc)
- [Which C#/.net Dependency Injection frameworks are worth looking into?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288/which-cnet-dependency-injection-frameworks-are-worth-looking-into)
- [Which Dependency Injection Tool Should I Use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148908/which-dependency-injection-tool-should-i-use)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Cool, that sounds interesting. I'm unclear on one aspect: can the IoC framework still use my handler functions? I mean, my dictionary is comprised of EventArg keys and handler function values. Ioc work with the handler function values still?

Comment: The handlers would need to be split out into separate classes that implemented an interface, and then you would call their "handleMessage" method.  Or, you could pass in strings, and use reflection to grab the methods, though that's kind of code-smelly.  I can edit with an example if you like.

Comment: Ok, so instead of FooBar knowing about 99 types, we'd have 99 types knowing about FooBar. I'd love to see a sample.

Comment: Thanks for the sample, Chris. I will look into this possibility. I just started using Ninject, so I'm new to IoC frameworks, but I will study your sample and see where to go from here.

Comment: Glad I could help.  One thing I like about Spring.NET is that it lets these mappings happen in text.  When I looked at Ninject, I only remember seeing programmatic definition of dependencies, which may or may not be suitable for your needs.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of having a different class for each message, use a flag that identifies the message.

That would drastically reduce the number of messages you have and increase maintainability.  My guess is that most of the message classes have about zero difference.

It's hard to pick an additional way of attacking this because the rest of the architecture is unknown (to me).

If you look at Windows, for example, it doesn't natively know how to handle each message that might be thrown about.  Instead, the underlying message handlers register callback functions with the main thread.

You might take a similiar approach.  Each message class would need to know how to handle itself and could register itself with the larger application.  This should greatly simplify the code and get rid of the tight coupling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We tried this some time ago, but it just shifts the complexity to the handler functions -- instead of 99 tiny handler functions, you have 20 very big handler functions. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the rest of your code, but I would try create a much smaller number of Event arg classes. Instead create a few that are similar to each other in terms of data contained and/or the way you handle them later and add a field that will tell you what exact type of event occured (probably you should use an enum).

Ideally you would not only make this constructor much more readable, but also the way the messages are handled (group messages that are handled in a similar way in a single event handler)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Chris Lively suggested the smaller number of event arg classes. We tried that, and it just shifts the complexity: instead of 99 tiny handler functions, we now have 20 big handler functions.

Comment: Regarding the "group messages that are handled in a similar way in a single event handler", yes, we do that. We have about 20 event args that are handled in the same way and get passed to the same handler.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are in need of a dispatching mechanism: depending on the event you receive, you want to execute different code.

You seem to be using the type system to identify the events, while it's actually meant to support polymorphism.  As Chris Lively suggests, you could just as well (without abusing the type system) use an enumerate to identify the messages.

Or you can embrace the power of the type system, and create a Registry object where every type of event is registered (by a static instance, a config file or whatsoever).  Then you could use the Chain of Responsibility pattern to find the proper handler.  Either the handler does the handling itself, or it may be a Factory, creating an object that handles the event.

The latter method looks a bit underspecified and overengineered, but in the case of 99 event types (already), it seems appropriate to me.

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion. Can you point me to more resources or post an example?