# .Net 4.0 Is There a Business Layer "Technology"?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, business-logic

I have a theoretical question about the .net framework.

As I see it Microsoft gave us bunch of technologies for different layers.

We have the ADO.NET and with the more improved Entity Framework for Data Access.

And ASP.NET for WEB UI. And even WCF for Facade and SOA.

But what in the middle, what do we have for the Business Layer? Is it just Referenced DLLs?

How do we deal with the Application Pooling this days? I remember using COM+ 10 yeas ago because the IIS couldn't handle the pressure.

Is Spring.Net is the best option available for injection?

Thanks,
   Ronny

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: The bottom line, I'm asking that tools, methodology and technology is most suitable for separating the Business Logic layer

Comment: For "separating logic", how about assemblies > namespaces > classes? What kind of tools are you looking for to help separating logic?

Comment: Sure, but then as I wrote, just referenced DLLs and not a designated technology for dealing with common issues as pooling and injection

Comment: If you looking for dependency injection tools, have a look here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148908/which-dependency-injection-tool-should-i-use

Comment: BTW, does the AppFabric server addresses some of the issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For dependency injection, you can use the [Unity Application Block](http://unity.codeplex.com/) from Microsoft Patterns & Practices.

You can also [use the Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291628.aspx).

**EDIT**: You might be looking for the entire [patterns & practices group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx).